How to copy values from array to array of structures?
In the code below I could use convenient syntax of std::ranges::transform to copy values from array of structures (AoS) to structure of arrays (SoA) (in this example, just one vector). Is there a way to do the same in opposite way, copying data from a specific field of structure when I need to copy values from SoA to AoS?
Specifically, is there a way to replace for-loop in the code below with some algorithm call (ranges of views would be preferrable)?
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

struct S
{
    float v1;
    float v2;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<S> aos = { { 1.0f, 2.0f } };
    std::vector<float> soa(aos.size());

    std::ranges::transform(aos, soa.begin(), &S::v1);

    std::cout << "soa value:" << soa[0] << std::endl;

    soa[0] = 3.0;

    // I want to replace this with something transform-like above
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < soa.size(); ++i)
    {
        aos[i].v1 = soa[i];
    }

    std::cout << "aos value:" << aos[0].v1 << std::endl;
}

Demo

Plain std::transform, with a suitable lambda? Or perhaps just a plain range for loop, similar to what you already have? Simplicity is usually a good thing, don't try to make things more complex than they need to be.

Something like std::ranges::transform(soa, aos.begin(), [](float f) -> S { return {f, -1.0f}; }); ...?

Maybe the problem is std::vector<float> soa;, working with (lazy) view aos | std::views::transform(&S::v1) might be better: each change to the view would be reflected in original.

You can copy the data into transform view of v1 without touching member v2:
auto as_v1 = aos | std::views::transform(&S::v1);
std::ranges::copy(soa, as_v1.begin());

Demo

Modifying as_v1 instead of soa might even be an option.
